# Touch ID Local Authentication produces Thread 12: EXC error

Tags: ios, swift, localauthentication

Currently, I have the following code in place.

```
if localAuthenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError) {
        
        localAuthenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString) { success, evaluateError in
            
            if success {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "settingChange", sender: self)                    //TODO: User authenticated successfully, take appropriate action
```

The code performs a segue, to another view Controller if the touch id is correctly authenticated, however when I try out the code I get this error:

[image]

I have tried the code without using the TouchID, and it works fine but I don't know why it produces the error upon the TouchID use. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you have an error message in console? Like main thread stuff? Because `performSegue()` is related to UI and has to be done in main thread. Also, it's saying `evaluatePolicy()` states: `A closure that is executed when policy evaluation finishes. This is evaluated on a private queue internal to the framework in an unspecified threading context.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an issue with performSegue operation. All UI changes related operations must be performed in main queue. Use `DispatchQueue` with main.

Try this and see (**Note:** *I've solution in Swift 4*):

```
if success {

  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "settingChange", sender: self)
  })

}
```